# Removing extra padding in DataTables columns

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

Hi so I have created JQuery DataTables that looks like this:

[image]

So my question is how to remove that too much padding in the "PICTURE" column?

This is how I initialize the table:

```
$('#violators_tbl').DataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 2,3 ] },
                { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                { "sWidth": "35%", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
                { "sWidth": "30%", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
                { "sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [ 3 ] },
            ],
        });
```

This is how I add rows to the table:

```
function update_table(violator){
        var img_str1 = '<img class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.front_temp_file_path + '\">';
        var img_str2 = '<img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.rear_temp_file_path + '\">';
        var img_str3 = '<img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.right_temp_file_path + '\">';
        var img_str4 = '<img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.left_temp_file_path + '\">';
        violators_table.dataTable().fnAddData([
            violator.violator_id,
            violator.get_full_name(),
            'Under Construction',
            img_str1 + img_str2 + img_str3 + img_str4,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier way would be to add the `sClass` option which adds a class to the designated columns. Thereafter, you can style your `my_class` according to your needs. This way, only the specific table instance is affected and not the others in your application.

```
$('#violators_tbl').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "sClass": "my_class", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ]
  } );
```

Comment: yes, I did this and I specified autowidth to be false. Thanks.

Comment: @JCFrane You can accept the this answer if it solved the issue. Am I right ArinCool ? :)

Comment: Yes I accept this, plus you have to specify the autowidth to be false. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways I see:

#### 1. CSS Class Change (Affects everywhere)

There is a css `class` defined for `THeads` in datatables look into that:

```
table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable thead td {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}
```

#### 2. Using Datatables API (Affects Specific Table Instance)

as mentioned in @ArinCool's answer:

[**aoColumnDefs:**](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)  It allows passing an array of columns by index and related style or function to be applied on that column. Here is an example

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {

                // mention css class-name and targetted column index (starts with zero from left)                    
                { "sClass": "class-name", "aTargets": [ 4 ] },

            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This will affect all instances of datatables in the application.

Comment: @ArinCool Yes, so it will be same everwhere. If we want specifically for this table only, we can write a special class for this table using a container > table > thead > td.

Comment: I add autowidth : false on configuration. It worked. Mehehehe.

Answer (score 1):

If this is related to the space between the pictures, you need to set something along the lines of `font-size: 0` in your CSS for that cell.  Something like:

```
td.picture-cell {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really don't want to touch CSS, you could do this with your JS:

```
var img_str1 = '<img class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.front_temp_file_path + '\"><!--';
var img_str2 = '--><img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.rear_temp_file_path + '\"><!--';
var img_str3 = '--><img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.right_temp_file_path + '\"><!--';
var img_str4 = '--><img style=\"margin-left: 10px;\" class=\"obj-pic\" src=\"' + Main.Vars.base_path + violator.left_temp_file_path + '\">';
```

What you're dealing with is rendering white-space.  That's the equivalent to a bunch of spaces that occur when code is formatted.  The first solution tells the browser (via CSS) to render your white-space characters as nothing (`font-size: 0;`).

The second solution wraps the end of one `img` tag to the beginning of the next `img` tag in a comment, which tells the HTML rendering engine to ignore all characters present between the opening of the comment (`<!--`) to the closing of the comment (`-->`).

Of course, if this isn't related to the space between the pictures, then this isn't your solution.  I couldn't really tell what padding exactly you're referencing, but based on your mention of the pictures, this was my best educated guess.

**Edit**

If you're looking for a fix for the padding at the *end* of the table cell, you need to set the table and subsequent cells' width to `auto` with CSS like so:

```
#violators_tbl {
  width: auto!important;
}
#violators_tbl td {
  width: auto!important;
}
```

From there, you can then readjust the widths for individual columns like this:

```
#violator_tbl td:nth-child(1) { /* This is the first column */
  width: 40px!important;
}
#violator_tbl td:nth-child(2) { /* This is the second column */
  width: 80px!important;
}
```

With the number in `nth-child` referencing the order in which the column appears (`1` for the first column, `2` for the second, etc.)

I wouldn't normally recommend the `!important` modifier, but since I have no idea what the CSS looks like that's driving that table, I won't bother trying to outrank the existing specificity.  Just keep in mind that `!important` is not an optimal pattern to follow under normal circumstances.

***Alternatively*** you can set the container for the table to a specified width as well.  What you're seeing with the extra padding at the end of that cell is the table filling its container.  If you give it a smaller container, then it will fill less space.

Try wrapping `#violators_tbl` in a div that looks like `<div class='table-shrink'><table id='violators_tbl'></table></div>` and then add this CSS:

```
.table-shrink {
  width: 400px; /* Whatever width works best for you goes here */
}
```